# Valgrind memcheck invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, valgrind, memcheck

This example can be compiled and works as expected.

```
1 #include  <stdlib.h>
2 #include  <stdio.h>
3 #include  <string.h>
4
5 char * getstr() {
6     return strdup("Hello");
7 }
8
9 void *memcpy2(void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
10 {
11     char * d = dest;
12     const char * s = src;
13
14     for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
15         d[i] = s[i];
16     }
17     return dest;
18 }
19
20 int main()
21 {
22     char buf[256];
23     char *str = getstr();
24
25     memset(buf, 0, 256);
26     memcpy2(buf, str, 255);
27
28     printf("%s\n", buf);
29
30     free(str);
31     return 0;
32 }
```

I reimplemented memcpy to have complete control over the test, making it independent from underlaying libc. As you can see, valgrind complains with this warning:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out 
==9479== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9479== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9479== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9479== Command: ./a.out
==9479== 
==9479== Invalid read of size 1
==9479==    at 0x4006B6: memcpy2 (k.c:15)
==9479==    by 0x400731: main (k.c:26)
==9479==  Address 0x5203046 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==9479==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9479==    by 0x4EC48D9: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==9479==    by 0x400673: getstr (k.c:6)
==9479==    by 0x4006F3: main (k.c:23)
==9479== 
Hello
==9479== 
==9479== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9479==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9479==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,030 bytes allocated
==9479== 
==9479== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9479== 
==9479== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

I don't understand why this "invalid read of size 1" message appears. It has not sense for me at all. Can some of you explain what is wrong with this code? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
[...]
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    d[i] = s[i];
}
[...]
```

Here `len` is 255, but the string pointed by `s` is less than 255 length, so you're going out of the array. You could maybe use the `'\0'` placed by `strdup()` to avoid this bug.

Comment: Yes! You are right. Now I see the problem! Thank you very much for you answers! :)

Answer (score 3):

In `main` the `str` variable points to a memory area of *six bytes* length (the string `"Hello"` is the five characters in the string plus terminator, `strdup` will allocate `strlen("Hello") + 1` bytes). Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

And you are going out of bounds since you want to read *255* bytes from this six-byte area.